# How to "italic or bold" description tag in html

Tags: html, tags, meta-tags

I am trying to bold keywords or text in meta description `<meta name="description" content=">`
 but I don't know how to do it.

How to bold or italic text (keyword) in meta-description tag,
and is it useful trick for SEO or not?

Answer (score 0):

**How to bold or italic text (keyword) in meta-description tag?**

The answer is: you don't. This requirement does not make any sense.

meta-description in HTML (`<meta>` tag) is used to indicate meta information of the page. It is not supposed to be rendered (and browser won't render it of course).

**Is it useful trick for SEO?**

No. Actually, content in the `<meta>` tag does not benefit SEO long long ago...